# Open graph website - can not administer

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I've added open graph meta tags to my website: http://www.stylistartshop.pl. I've liked the site and I should be able to administer this website via facebook or have administer link by the like button on my website. None of those is actually in place.

I've checked the website on facebook linter http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it shows no errors and the admin id matches my id.

I've looked for help on here and there and have seen couple reports of the same problem but no answer.

So my question is:

- if I added the meta tags and run the website through facebook
  linter 24h ago should I be able to administer it by going to account -> manage sites or by going to my website and clicking on like and accessing admin link just by its side?
- if response is to a is true what can I do now? Any ideas?
- if there is already a facebook site called stylistartshop can that be the source of problem?

Thanks a lot for help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as yourself? The Debugger should give you an admin link if you are logged in as the admin.