# Facebook associated page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I added a like button to a page, somebody liked it but there wasnt fb:admins tag. Now the admin tag is filled but there is no new "page" in my profile associated with this page. How to fix it? I want Facebook to create a page for already created page. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Facebook documentation on the Open Graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph):

> Note that the Open Graph protocol is currently designed to support real-life objects. If your URL is a piece of content — such as a news article, photo, video, or similar — you should set og:type to article (see below). Pages of type article do not have publishing rights, and will not show up on user's profiles because they are not real world objects.

If your page is not set up as an article, you should use [Facebook's URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to determine the Open Graph tags that Facebook has retrieved from your webpage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This page is located in root folder of the site and has og:type "website". Am I right facebook doesnt create page for root of the site? [link to webpage](http://weheartpics.com)

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/q/7721214/113527, it looks like you have to Like the page and then click on the Admin link that should appear next the Like button. If it is still not appearing, then your question is probably actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7717172/113527 .

Comment: I loged in as user with admin id, but there is no administrate button

Comment: Based on the answer submitted by a Facebook employee on the second StackOverflow question I mentioned, this sounds like a Facebook bug. I would check http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ in order to add your experience to a pre-existing bug or create a new one if one does not already exist.